# mksquashfs: how to include full absolute directory paths inside the squashfs image?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, archive, disk-image, squashfs

When I create a squashfs image from multiple directories such as:

- /bin/
- /usr/bin/
- /usr/local/bin/
- /some/other/random/folder/
- /another/long/path/

If I use command...

```
mksquashfs /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /some/other/random/folder /another/long/path MyNewImage.squashfs
```

It gives me an image with these top-level folders:

- bin/
- bin_1/
- bin_2/
- folder/
- path/

I want my image to contain the full paths from the original filesystem:

- bin/
- usr/bin/
- usr/local/bin/
- some/other/random/folder/
- another/long/path/

Is there any simple way to do this without first making copies or moving the original files before creating the image?

Answer (score 3):

Based on @meuh's answer (which was a little bit hard for me to grasp):

```
mksquashfs / MyNewImage.squashfs -wildcards -e \
  !(bin|usr|some|another) \
  usr/!(bin|local) \
  usr/local/!(bin) \
  some/!(other) \
  some/other/!(random) \
  some/other/random/!(folder) \
  another/!(long) \
  another/long/!(path)
```

I'd also be glad of a more comprehensible plus more concise possibility and filed a feature request for it: https://github.com/plougher/squashfs-tools/issues/80 .

**UPDATE**

You can use the `-no-strip` option with a newer version:

```
mksquashfs /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin \
    /some/other/random/folder /another/long/path \
    MyNewImage.squashfs -no-strip
```

Comment: "-no-strip" is useful, thanks! I find it inconvenient that man page is not updated.

Answer (score 2):

There probably is no *simple way*, but you can do it with a lot of effort by using the extended wildcard exclude syntax. This may not be documented in the man page but is mentioned more in the [README](https://github.com/Othernet-Project/squashfs-tools/blob/master/README). However, for details of the syntax you need to see the man page for `fnmatch(3)`.

Basically, you can use `!(somedir)` as an exclude to *not* exclude, so you end up only including that directory.  Imagine you have the following example tree in `/tmp`

```
$ mkdir -p a/b   d/e   d/e2
$ touch    a/b/c d/e/f d/e2/f2
```

and you only want to copy `a` and `d/e` whilst preserving these full pathnames.  You can use

```
$ echo '!(a)' >exclude
$ mksquashfs /tmp mysq -ef exclude -wildcards
$ echo -e '!(d)/\nd/!(e)' >exclude
$ mksquashfs /tmp mysq -ef exclude -wildcards
```

Listing the filesystem with `unsquashfs -l mysq` produces the output

```
squashfs-root/a
squashfs-root/a/b
squashfs-root/a/b/c
squashfs-root/d
squashfs-root/d/e
squashfs-root/d/e/f
```

Each time, the source directory is `/tmp`, but the first time we exclude everything except directory `a`, and the second time we exclude everything except directory `d` and `d/e`.  This uses a multi-level exclude file where on each line we exclude one more directory step in the path except the one that is to be retained.

---

A simpler solution is to create the wanted hierarchy of directories somewhere, and `mount -bind` the final directory to the real directory.
For example,

```
$ mkdir -p a/usr/local/bin a/some/other/bin
$ sudo mount -o bind /usr/local/bin a/usr/local/bin
$ sudo mount -o bind /some/other/bin a/some/other/bin
$ mksquashfs a ~/mysq
$ sudo umount a/usr/local/bin a/some/other/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

man mksquashfs:

```
   -keep-as-directory
       if  one source directory is specified, create a root directory con‐
       taining that directory, rather than the contents of the directory.
```

Comment: Already tried that.  It doesn't do it.